# "No such file or directory" when synchronizing a local file with percent sign to remote directory with WinSCP

Tags: powershell, winscp, winscp-net

I have file with name `%253csvg%2fonload=alert(1)%253e.jpg-131x94`

I am trying to sync the files to remote server using WinSCP .NET assembly `Session.SynchronizeDirectories`

I am getting error

> **"No such file or directory"**

But I see the file name in the error is `%3csvg/onload=alert(1)%3e.jpg-131x94` some few of the words are missing.

I am using WinSCP 5.9.6 product version.

```
$FTPSourceFolder = "D:\...\00"
$FTPDestionationFolder = "/storage/../00"

$synchronizationResult = $session.SynchronizeDirectories(
    [WinSCP.SynchronizationMode]::Remote, $FTPSourceFolder,$FTPDestionationFolder, $True, $False) 
$synchronizationResult.check()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinSCP will by default URL-decode the local file name.

If you do not want that, you can turn this feature off:

```
$transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
$transferOptions.AddRawSettings("ReplaceInvalidChars", "0")
$synchronizationResult =
    $session.SynchronizeDirectories(
        [WinSCP.SynchronizationMode]::Remote, 
        $FTPSourceFolder,$FTPDestionationFolder, $True, $False,
        $transferOptions)
```

References:

- https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_transfer_custom
- https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawtransfersettings